# Cannot run Ubuntu VM through HyperV after installing xorg

Tags: xorg, virtualization, remote-desktop, xrdp, hyper-v

I am trying to set up an ubuntu VM through Hyper-V Manager, and configure it so that I can conenct using windows RDC.

My steps are:

1. Create a VM using Hyper-V Manager with an installation of Ubuntu 18.04.3 (20480MB Ram, 4 vritual processors, 200GB Disk).
2. Install XRDP and XFCE4 to allow remote connection

   sudo apt install xrdp

   sudo apt install xfce4

   echo xfce4-session > ~/.xsession

   sudo service xrdp restart
3. Install xorg and dependencies which are required for the remote connection to work

   sudo apt-get install xorg-video-abi-23 xserver-xorg-core

   sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp

At any point after running step 3 and restarting the VM, whenever I try to connect to the VM through Hyper-V manager, it gets stuck on the login screen (it displays the login screen but does not respond to any mouse or keyboard input)

Without running step 3, the remote connection from windows doesn't work (it allows me to login but then times out)

Is this an issue with Hyper-V? Or is there another way to resolve this so the VM is accessible both via RDP and via Hyper-V manager.